# redis sub/pub in or out of io.connect callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io

Should I put the redis subscription event out of the `io.connect` callback if I want to send the data to everyone who is connected? Or is it better to put it inside the `io.connect` like this:

```
    io.on('connection', function(socket){ 
      sub.on('message',function(channel,msg){
       Project.findAll({ where: {id: msg} },{raw:true}).success(function(d) {
       console.log(d);
       io.sockets.emit("activities",d);
      })
     });
    });
```

Would there be any difference?

Node.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require("socket.io").listen(http),
    redis = require("redis"),
    Sequelize = require('sequelize');

    var pub = redis.createClient();
    var sub = redis.createClient();
    sub.subscribe('global');

    app.get('/p/:tagId', function(req, res){ 
       res.render('index.html')
    });

    sub.on('message',function(channel,msg){
      Project.findAll({ where: {id: msg} },{raw:true}).success(function(d) {
      console.log(d);
      io.emit("activities",d);
     })
    });

    io.on('connection', function(socket){ 

     //** code **//
    })
```

Can anyone show me what's wrong with the node.js's code?

Comment: What your problem is? Describe problem.

Comment: Both of your code is wrong, redis object has no `on('message')` event, and you only have access to the `io` events in there. For read [node-redis](http://howtonode.org/redis-pubsub). Change your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second code sample looks correct. You don't want to put the `sub.on('message', function(channel, msg) {` inside the socket.io connection handler. That would add a new event handler every time someone connects.

Did you test if it is working? You need to publish something onto the channel `global` for the `message` callback to be triggered.

```
pub.publish('global', 'here is a message');
```